# Can I use django tags in ckeditor?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, ckeditor

I want to ask you: Can I use django-template tags in ckeditor? 

[click here to see ckeditor and tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Q95.png)

result:

[click here to see results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbafj.png)

P.S.: I use `{{ post.body|safe }}` in my html template